# Item selector search function without textfield

Tags: extjs5, itemselector, tbar

im pretty new to Extjs and trying to implement item selector with search functionality .

working example :

https://fiddle.sencha.com/fiddle/jiu

but my requirement little vary from this example, without text field need to search the values

attached the sample image, what exactly i want to implement.

https://i.stack.imgur.com/F1Muh.png

Any one help me to implement this.

Thanks in Advance.

Comment: I didn't understand what you want. You want to implement the search without a text box? where you going to type what you searching for?

Comment: without text box i need to implement open this link you ll get better idea search.https://i.stack.imgur.com/F1Muh.png